# ErrorException undefined variable data in view

Tags: laravel

> (2/2) ErrorException
>   Undefined variable: data(View: E:\xampp\htdocs\snipe-it\resources\views\hardware\bulk-checkout.blade.php)

**My Controller**

```
public function bulkAssetImport($assets_ids)
    {
        $data='testersdfsdf';
        return Redirect('hardware/bulk-checkout',compact('data'));      
    }
```

**My blade.php File**

```
 @foreach
       {{$data}}
 @endforeach
```

I tried different ways but no use, Please help me

Comment: Please show your route define in `web.php`

Comment: Simply you need to check view working without use `$data` variable.

Comment: without $data variable my view file working

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display data in html. Yo can do something like this.

```
<p>{{ $data }}</p>
```

If you want to loop data in your html

In your controller

```
public function bulkAssetImport($assets_id)
{
     $data= array(
        array('name'=> 'John doe', 'age' => 22),
        array('name'=> 'Doe not', 'age' => 22),
     );
     return view('hardware/bulk-checkout',compact('data'));      
 }
```

In your html:

```
 @foreach($data as $d)
      My name is: {{$d->name}} and my age is: {{ $d->age }} 
 @endforeach
```

Comment: i tried what you have mentioned in above. but not working, again same error showing